# Getting started with Android Development: How do I place buttons

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I feel really silly for asking this , but how do I place buttons correctly in graphical layout for main.xml.  I am trying to place buttons in linear layout but they will only be placed vertically or horizontally depending on the orientation.  Once i reach the end the buttons simply overlap.  I want to start making basic applications in eclipse with the android sdk and eventually try games but this user interface creator so far has me stumped. Is there a proper way of creating a ui that I am not doing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Google.com:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

There are plenty of resources, answered questions (on this site alone), and tutorials that will get you used to using xml layouts for your Android applications.  I would recommend working through this:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html